# EmberJS - the run loop is cleared with "asyn/await" instead of the use of "then"

Tags: testing, ember.js, async-await, ember-data

I have a strange behavior with run loop in a test (yes, for everybody is difficult ;-) ) and with the babel plugin async to generator transform.

First, I have "an old school code":

```
await Ember.run(function() {
  return task.save().then(() => {
    subtask_1 = task.create_subtask();
    return subtask_1.save();
  }).then(() => {
    subtask_2 = task.create_subtask();
    return subtask_2.save();
  }).then(() => {
    subtask_3 = task.create_subtask();
    return subtask_3.save();
  }).then(() => {
    subtask_4 = task.create_subtask();
    return subtask_4.save();
  }).then(() => {
    return subtask_4.promise_priorize_before(subtask_2);
  });
});
```

**It works**. ;-)

But, if I tried, I think the equivalent code with the "new way", I have an error:

```
await Ember.run(async function() {
  console.log(Ember.run.currentRunLoop);
  await task.save();
  console.log(Ember.run.currentRunLoop);

  subtask_1 = task.create_subtask();
  console.log(Ember.run.currentRunLoop);
  await subtask_1.save();
  console.log(Ember.run.currentRunLoop); // <---- null here

  subtask_2 = task.create_subtask();     // <---- crash here
  console.log(Ember.run.currentRunLoop);
  await subtask_2.save();

  subtask_3 = task.create_subtask();
  await subtask_3.save();

  subtask_4 = task.create_subtask();
  await subtask_4.save();

  return subtask_4.promise_priorize_before(subtask_2);
});
```

I don't understand why, but the current run loop is cleared after a simple "save" of Ember data.

The error is "Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode,… any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run" because Ember.run.currentRunLoop is null.

Have you an idea?

Frédéric

[a beginning of response]

I begin to understand the problem. Many Ember methods don't start to do their job when they are called. They only schedule to do their job!

```
//                           ┌──────────────────────────────┐                              
//                           │  ┌────────────────────────┐  │                              
//                           │  │         BEGIN          │  │                              
//                           │  └────────────────────────┘  │                              
//                           │                              │                              
//                           │                              │                              
//                           │                              │ 1: schedule                  
// ┌──────────────────┐   2  │  ┌────────────────────────┐  │    save      ┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐   
// │ returned PROMISE │◀─────┼──│          SAVE          │──┼─────────────▶│ │ │ │ │ │ │──┐
// └──────────────────┘      │  └────────────────────────┘  │              └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘  │
//           ▲               │                              │                             │
//                           │                              │                             │
//           │               │                              │                             │
//                           │  ┌────────────────────────┐  │                             │
//           └ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┼ ─│          END           │◀─┼─────────────────────────────┘
//              5: resolve   │  └────────────────────────┘  │          3: flush            
//              the promise  └──────────────────────────────┘           queues             
//                                     4: call the                                         
//                                   adapter for the                                       
//                                        save                                             
//                                                                                         
//                                    6: clear the                                         
//                                     current run                                         
//                                        loop
```

So, when I use "then()", it is a part of the returned promise, and so, the scheduled promise isn't finished after the save is resolved, but only after the last "then()". And so, the current run loop isn't cleared.

But why when I use generator async/await, it isn't the same thing?

And why the Ember documentation doesn't show when a method schedules its job??

Comment: did you try debug why and where it set to null?

Comment: maybe you can share code ( to run/ debug )?

Comment: thanks for your response. yes, I debug my code (see my response in my question above), but it's difficult to follow the execution of a promise AND the execution of the run loop!! and it's difficult to share a test in JSBin or Ember twiddle.

Comment: It's sad that I can't help you. What did you used for schema in ASCII ?

Comment: I used http://monodraw.helftone.com/ ;-)

Comment: What environment/transpiler do you use to run the async function? Maybe its a problem there?

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.11.5 with Ember CLI: 2.4.2,Ember: 2.4.5, Ember Data : 2.5.2, node: 4.4.2